# How to pass a value of one parameter to another in Azure Devops Task group

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Task group parameter SonarEndpoint which is used to select service connection of sonar endpoint. The parameter passed as a variable in one of the task.

i need to pass the value of this parameter to another parameter defined in the same task group at the task group level.

Comment: Hi @Balaji Tendster, how are things going? Have you tried the suggestions in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it. Any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case im having a service connection parameter at the task group level which i need to validate and execute a task based on that condition.

Eg : If the service connection is selected as "XXX" in task group a proxy task should run
If the service connection is selected as "YYY" in the task group  the proxy task
should be skipped

So i used a custom condition which helps me in this perspective to solve the above scenario. As it is not a string parameter i could not get the exact value for my validation instead i got some id for that service connection value.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not supported that directly passing the value of a parameter to another in the task group.

As a workaround, you can use a pipeline variable to pass the value between the parameters in the task group. Here you need to add a shell task (e.g **Bash**) in the task group to execute the [**SetVariable**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable) command to set a pipeline variable with the value of the task group parameter.

The GIF screenshot below shows an example as reference.

[image]

Comment: The above scenario works for the String parameter but not for dropdown parameter in my case Service connection. But it helps, thanks for sharing your knowledge